# Search em lista de checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de fazer uma busca em tempo real. Parecido com o [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), porém em uma "lista" de `Checkbox`.
Segue minha lista de `CheckBox`

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div>
    <label>
        <input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="1"><input name="chk" type="hidden" value="false">
        Profa. Ariadne Tramontina Morais
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="2"><input name="chk" type="hidden" value="false">
        Profa. Beatriz Pagnanelli Van Sebroeck
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="3"><input name="chk" type="hidden" value="false">
        Prof. Joao
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <label>
        <input id="chk" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="4"><input name="chk" type="hidden" value="false">
        Profa. Zuleide
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer fazer? Quer ordenar uma tabela por input das checkbox? onde tem o código da tabela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso utilizando `jQuery` apenas aplicando o id *search-criteria* em sua caixa de pesquisa.
Aplique uma classe em sua `div` pai, no caso vou utilizar a classe *teste*.
Coloque o nome dos indivíduos dentro de `<span>`.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h4>Pesquisa por Nome</h4>
                    <input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
        var g = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var value = $.trim($("#search-criteria").val());
        if (value.length > 0) {
            $("span").each(function () {
                var s = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                if (s.indexOf(g) != -1) {
                    $(this).parent().closest('.teste').show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().closest('.teste').hide();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.teste').hide();
        }
    });
```